# UITableView with static cells without cellForRowAtIndexPath. How to set clear background?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a static UITableView and everything is laid out on the Storyboard. In cellForRowAtIndexPath i simply use

```
return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and the tableview works great. However I want to set the cells backgrounds to [UIColor clearColor]
How can I do this? The table has 30 cells, each one different.

Thanks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this will work, because I've never tried using `super` to manage the cells. If your code works with `super`, then you should be able to get away with doing this to set the background color:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Either way, this seems to me like a strange way of doing things. Normally the cells are created and reused in the method itself, as per the default `UITableView` boiletplate code, without calling `super`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. As the table is very long and every cell is completely different and static, I found it easier to just set them all in Storyboard and create IBOutlet's to all UILabels that needed data.

Answer (score 22):

Try this delegate method:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: This method did work, thanks. However I selected jon's answer to be the correct one as it seemed the correct place to set the cell. Thanks

Comment: The accepted answer works but is unnecessarily verbose and complex. `willDisplayCell:` is far more straightforward and perfectly suited for the use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a method and call it in your viewDidLoad in order to get all the cells and do whatever you want with them you can use this:

```
NSArray *visibleIndexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
```

To get all the index paths of the currently viewable cells

Then iterate over them in the following way

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[visibleIndexPaths objectAtIndex:i]];
  // Do your setup
}
```

You can also reference [this Apple developer document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) the part "**The Technique for Static Row Content**"